# Creating a Cloudformation DBCluster from a snapshot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-aurora

We are currently having trouble recreating our stack in CloudFormation. We basically want to create a new Aurora cluster from a snapshot, and attach a DB instance to it.

I have successfully created a DBCluster from a snapshot using the `SnapshotIdentifier` value, but this does not create an instance inside the cluster. If I then add a DBInstance to the cluster in cloudformation using `DBClusterIdentifier` it says that it needs the `MasterUsername` and `MasterUserPassword` values. But my understanding is that these are part of the snapshot.

I feel like I am missing something very fundemental with the aurora CloudFormation stuff.

This is out DBCluster and DBInstance properties:

```
  "DBCluster": {
    "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBCluster",
    "Properties": {
      "Port": "3306",
      "Engine": "aurora",
      "EngineVersion": "5.6.10a",
      "SnapshotIdentifier": {
        "Ref": "MainSnapshotIdenifer"
      },
      "DBSubnetGroupName": {
        "Ref": "DatabaseSubnetGroup"
      }
    }
  },
  "DBInstance": {
    "Type": "AWS::RDS::DBInstance",
    "Properties": {
      "DBClusterIdentifier": {
        "Ref": "DBCluster"
      },
      "DBInstanceIdentifier": "HanzsDBInstance",
      "DBInstanceClass": "db.r3.large",
      "Engine": "aurora",
      "DBParameterGroupName": {
        "Ref": "DBParameterGroup"
      },
      "PubliclyAccessible": "true",
      "DBSubnetGroupName": {
        "Ref": "DatabaseSubnetGroup"
      },
      "DBSecurityGroups": [
        {
          "Ref": "DatabaseSecurityGroup"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```